# openssl, recover passphrase with encrypted and not encrypted file

Tags: openssl, passphrase

Some of my colleague give me 2 file of private key (one is encrypted and the other is decrypted) and a passphrase. But it seems that is the wrong passphrase.

Is it even possible to recover the pass phrase with the ecrypted and decrypted private key files?

Comment: Is it the _same_ private key, once in an encrypted file and once in a file that is not encrypted?

Comment: Yes, that's what my colleague said to me.

Comment: Theoretically recoverable by bruteforcing, but chances are low in practical terms (unless the passphrase was quite weak). Simplest solution: Use the not encrypted file to create a _new_ encrypted file with a _new_ passphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).  From the Wikipedia article quoted above:

> The known-plaintext attack (KPA) is an attack model for cryptanalysis
> where the attacker has access to both the plaintext (called a crib),
> and its encrypted version (ciphertext). These can be used to reveal
> further secret information such as secret keys and code books.

Modern encryption algorithms such as AES are designed to be highly resistant to known-plaintext attacks, however earlier encryption algorithms were susceptible to known-plaintext attacks.  For example, with XOR encryption, it is trivial to find the encryption key given the ciphertext and the plaintext.

Comment: Plus an AES-level attack even if possible would only give the key, not the _passphrase_ from which the key was derived as the Q asked. And since the key derivation is salted, it wouldn't give the key for any other file using the same passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comment above, the simplest solution in the given case (as per OP, they have the unencrypted key file):
Use the *not* encrypted file to create a new encrypted file with a *new* passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in unencrypted.key -out new.key
```

Comment: That command does not create an encrypted key file (and assumes PEM which is not always the case even with OpenSSL). If you add `-$cipher` it creates the 'legacy' format file using very poor and usually breakable key derivation (EVP_BytesToKey(niter=1), see numerous existing Qs). `pkcs8 -topk8 [-v2 plaincipher]` or in 1.0.0 up for PEM only `pkey -$cipher` is much better.